# Get the Top10 values without repeating any item from the category Column

Tags: excel, vba

What I would like to achieve is to obtain the top ten values for each client in column (P) using as the parameter the `column(Q)= NumFab`. Then list the found number for `Order`, `Client`, and `NumbFab` in a new table `=range("B26: B35")`. The restriction is that it cannot repeat a client after is found.

```
    Sub FindTop10()
 Dim rngDatos As Range
 Dim lNumEntradas As Long
 Dim dOriginal As Variant
 Dim Celda As Range
 Dim RtopTen As Range
 
     Set rngDatos = h_Calc.Range("o4", h_Calc.Cells(Rows.Count, "x").End(xlUp))
     
     dOriginal = rngDatos 'save data original
     
     'set off notifications
     With Application
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
     End With
     'if there is a problem set apps back
     On Error GoTo CleanExit
        With h_Calc
            rngDatos.Sort key1:=Range("x4"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess
        End With
    
        ultLinea = h_Calc.Cells(Rows.Count, "o").End(xlUp).Row
        
        h_Calc.Range("b26:d35").Clear
        
        Set RtopTen = h_Calc.Range("C26:C35")
    With h_Calc


        i = 4
        For Each Celda In RtopTen
        
            Do Until Celda.Value = .Cells(i, "P").Value
                Celda.Offset(0, -1) = .Cells(i, "o").Value
                Celda = Format(.Cells(i, "p"), "@")
                Celda.Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(i, "Q").Value
            Loop
             
        Next Celda
        
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a significance to the output region?  I am unsure if you want this to be on a per-Client basis, or how the Client is being selected, as this would most likely involve an if statement to determine appropriate entries.

Comment: I would imagine you want a separate table with the Client codes in a single column (e.g., A), then top order in next column (e.g., B), descending to at most 10 columns.  This would most likely need to have a separate column for order number... is it possible to have a column in your current table dedicated to labeling 1, 2, 3, etc., per Client?

Comment: Hello Cyril thanks for responding. the Clients list is from a fabrication list where I have to present a report with the Top10 clients that ordered a product from the company in the last three months, and Yes we can have a labeling column

Comment: Frank, I think I found a discrepancy between points... are you finding the top 10 clients, or the top 10 list of orders per Client?  Your comment response compared to the first sentence would be different sets of code.  Separate from that thought, if you have a labeling column (a helper column of sorts, you can sum up values per client (sumifs doesn't even need VBA), then sort by highest value (i will say this part *may* need VBA as I have had issues with Excel inherently recognizing the values produced from formulas).

Comment: Cyril, I am trying to find the top 10 order, the problem is that one client may have different orders that could fall in the top 10, but I don't want the same client to be listed two or more times, instead, when a client is found not need to be listed again. Let say a client has an order than fall  No.1 in the list, then for the second place, I want the second higher order which will be the No 1 for the next client.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think to get a top 10 order, and this is going to look wonky with purposefully triggering errors, is the below code I use to find unique values in a column, which I have added a stipulation to stop at 10 iterations.  You would have this code occur after you have sorted for most orders.

```
Dim i As Long, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
With Sheets("Source")
    lr1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
End With
With Sheets("Destination")
    For i = 2 To lr1
        If lr2 = 12 Then Exit Sub 'assumes header in row 1 and you want to count from 2~11
        lr2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        On Error Resume Next
        If Application.Match(Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 4), .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr2, 1)), 0) > lr2 Then .Cells(lr2 + 1, 1).Value = Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 4).Value
    Next i
End With
```

This would take a single point of data, though you can edit to use ranges.